# Knockout.js Best Practice for binding Multiple ObservableArrays in one ViewModel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm fairly new the Knockout.js, but I've been successful throwing together a few CRUD templates that interacts with a simple WebAPI service.  Now I want to move on to more complex structures and I'm already tripped up on a fairly common situation: multiple dropdown lists on a single html form.

I understand I could build a ViewModel such as this:

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable();
    self.customers = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.selectedState = ko.observable();
    self.states = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

And then I'd bind each select list to the appropriate property.  While this should work, I feel like there is a better way to handle it.  I've thought about breaking each list into it's own ViewModel, but that seems like overkill. I want to get into good MVVM habits early, and am looking to rebuild an older system using these new techniques, so any directions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are looking for is now called `Component` in knockoutjs version 3.2.0. To understand this you can see this presentation of Steve Anderson the founder of knockoutjs.

[Architecting large Single Page Applications with Knockout.js](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/)

This presentation tells us to create a component which will be based on two things.

1. Viewmodel
2. template

Then there are two ways to use it.

1.HTML tag way. Example `<name-editor></name-editor>`
2 Using component binding `<div data-bind="component: 'name-editor'"></div>`

One thing to remember is that component will be completely independent and you can call as many instances of component on your page as you want and each will be working independently.

Here are two tutorials that will lead you to the right path.

[Knockout.js 3.2 Preview : Components](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html)

[Dipping your feet into KnockoutJS Components](http://sumitmaitra.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/dipping-your-feet-into-knockoutjs-components/)

Comment: That looks like a good path to explore.  So in this case each component would serve as a mini-VM, which contains the relevant properties for each.  This could probably be expanded on (if not already) to have a generic VM for select list components where you pass in the observables and the component links it all up.  Thanks!